# how to make jquery async/parallel requests?

Tags: jquery

My use case is when a user clicks on a search button.
I'd make a request to the search action and this action can take up to 1 minute to finish.
The search action is taking too long so I want to show the progressing status to the user.
Then I thought I'd make another ajax request to get the search status.
But the search status action is always pending and waiting for the search action to finish.  I've tried my different ways but they don't seem to work.  Any help would be really appreciated.

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function() {

       // kickoff search action
       $.ajax({
            url: doSearchUrl,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "keyword=" + keyword,
            success: function (json) {
            }
        });

       // this action is always waiting for the search action to finish first
        $.ajax({
            url: doGetSearchStatusUrl,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "tk=" + tk,
            success: function (json) {
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: You have lost me. Please review your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a predefined timeout for when the operation fails, in the absence of access to the actual progress of the operation, you can display a progress bar which progressively increments such that it would reach 100% when the operation times out.

Comment: My progressing status return partial result message like when you do a dog pedigree search.  It would say I found the dad of your dog.  I found the mom of your dog...etc..